# axios.delete ok in postman, 401 on server

Tags: vue.js, axios, fetch, http-status-code-401

Deleting a record form my webapp results in a 401 error.

I tried:

```
   axios.delete(`../api/cards/${id}`,{headers:{Authorization:'Bearer '+this.token, 'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}})
```

as well as

```
   const formData = new FormData();
               formData.append('_method', 'DELETE');  // axios setting
                const config = {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` }
                }; 
                axios.post(`../api/cards/${id}`,
                    formData,     
                    config
                )
```

result is:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/cards/21
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

When I use Postman with the token taken from the chrome dev Application Local storage it works like a charm.

I have no clue where to start debugging this. Any suggestions that could lead to a solution?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, examine the AJAX request being made.  Are the header values what you expect?  In what way(s) does the request differ from what's in Postman?

Comment: Ah, you mean the Request headers? They read: ```Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer undefined
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: game_user_auth=eyJpdiI6Ijh.... ```. In Postman I see: ```bearer: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC ....```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I forgot to add the token to the ...mapState[ 'token']. It was not collected form the vuex store.

Comment: Then clearly `this.token` is `undefined`.  What do you expect it to be and why?  Where is it ever defined?  It sounds like the problem is outside the code shown here and has nothing to do with AJAX requests or Axios or Postman.